# What does "Clear Graphics Context" means?

Tags: ios, uiview

In Xcode 4.3, when you choose some UIView object placed in .xib, you can find out there is an option saying "Clear Graphics Context". What does it means?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> When it is checked, iOS will draw the entire area covered by the
>   object in transparent black before it actually draws the object.
> It is
>   rarely needed.

---

[Beginning IOS 5 Development: Exploring the IOS SDK, page 81, paragraph3.](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=sikKz-oQNFIC&lpg=PA88&ots=Bs5y9c16Pn&dq=Clear%20Graphics%20Context%20checkbox&hl=ru&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: When do we have to "draw the entire area covered by the object in transparent black before it actually draws the object." ?

Comment: One example of when you might use it is if you have a label (clear background) and you're changing the text.  Without this flag, the new text is drawn over the old text.  With the box checked, the label area is "erased" before the next text is drawn.

Comment: what is transparent black? when it is transparent it has no color, and "transparent black"?

Comment: @RainCast Color is represented in 4 components: Red, green, blue and alpha (transparency). So even if something is completely transparent, there are still color values present, they are just not visible.
This becomes important when you have a gradient: A gradient from white to transparent white looks different than a gradient from white to transparent black.

Answer (score 10):

It will apply an OpenGL **`"clear context"`** before starting the DrawRect function of the UIView:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Is there any performance cost If applying an OpenGL "clear context"? I see this option is checked by default.

Comment: OpenGL is a State Machine, so with every call comes an expense. That said, those are just two calls and quite worth it if you want that behavior.